# node-async doesn't execute callback

Tags: node.js, async.js

**The Code**

I tried this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/async to implement series & parallel processing.

For small cases it works, well, however when I try to run this, I get an unexpected behavior:

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        console.log('one');
        callback();
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log('two');
        async.parallel([
            function(callback){
                console.log('two-one');
                callback();
            },
            function(callback){
                async.series([
                    function (callback){
                        console.log('two-two-one');
                        callback();
                    },
                    function (callback){
                        console.log('two-two-two');
                        callback();
                    }
                ]);
            }
        ], callback);
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log('three');
        callback();
    }
]);
```

**The Expected Result**

The code should print `one`, `two`, `two-one`, and `three` in series. However, after print `two-one`, I want to print `two-two-one` and `two-two-two` in parallel.

The expected result is either:

```
one
two
two-one
two-two-one
two-two-two
three
```

or

```
one
two
two-one
two-two-two
two-two-one
three
```

**The Real Result**

Unfortunately, `three` is never printed.

```
one
two
two-one
two-two-one
two-two-two
```

**The Question**

Is there something wrong with my code/understanding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async series take a last argument as function to grab the final result.

Please pass parallel callback as second argument of async series.

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        console.log('one');
        callback();
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log('two');
        async.parallel([
            function(callback){
                console.log('two-one');
                callback();
            },
            function(callback){
                async.series([
                    function (callback){
                        console.log('two-two-one');
                        callback();
                    },
                    function (callback){
                        console.log('two-two-two');
                        callback();
                    }
                ],callback);// pass parallel callback to trace the outcome 
            }
        ], callback);
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log('three');
        callback();
    }
],console.log);// use console.lg to get the final outcome of series
```

Comment: I just change the line with `// pass parallel callback to trace the outcome` comment. And it works perfectly. Just now there is a second argument in async.series, and it seems to be undocumented :(. Thx btw

Comment: @Kundu please use a 4 space indentation for code blocks instead of backticks.

Comment: @AlexisTyler Sorry for the inconvenience. I have used a mobile browser to add the answer. Thanks for the edit BTW.